# How to make a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, case-insensitive

When I make an array of strings the `equalsIgnorecase` doesn't recognize it, in eclipse it's suggesting me to change the array to something else, vice verca.

```
  public void onChat(PlayerChatEvent event) {
      Player player = event.getPlayer();
      String[] curse = new String[] {"rude1", "rude2", "rudeN"};
      if (event.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase(curse)) {
        event.setCancelled(true);
        player.sendMessage("Don't Swear");
     }
 }
}
```

It's my curse filter for my video game.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Heed the eclipse error :P

Comment: L33t speak isn't caught by those filters, for starters.

Comment: equalsIgnoreCase takes in a String, not an array of string. You have to iterate through the array if you want to do the checking. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)

Comment: @JasonYeo:  At least link to Java 6 APIs when you do that...Java 1.4.2 is so old school... :P

Comment: @Makoto oops, I totally missed the version number. Anyway, here's the link to it, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String).

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do a loop through curses to check each one.

```
for (String c : curse) {
  ... do check ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say, (sorry, i'm fairly new to java).

Answer (score 1):

Continue with what user2089674 suggested.

I guess you want to filter out messages containing curse words, so instead of using equalsIgnoreCase, use contains instead?

That is

```
for (String c : curse) {

  if(event.getMessage().contains(c)){
       ......punish bad players..
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been stated before, but the idea is that the [method signature for `String.equalsIgnoreCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) does not accept a `String[]` as a parameter.

Looking at it a bit closer - You may have a `String[]`, but that isn't the same as a `String`.  Think of it as you needing a $1 bill to use the vending machine, but you only have a $20 - it ain't going to work.

Hence, you are required to iterate over all elements of that array and feed them through `equalsIgnoreCase`.

Here's three ways to do it:

1. A simple for loop

   ```
   for(int i = 0; i < curse.length(); i++) {
       if(curse[i].equalsIgnoreCase(event.getMessage()) {
           // logic
       }
   }
   ```
2. An [enhanced for](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) loop

   ```
   for(String badWord : curse) {
       if(badWord.equalsIgnoreCase(event.getMessage()) {
         // logic
       }
   }
   ```
3. Converting the array to a List collection through [`Arrays.asList(T... a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/ArrayList.html) and using an `Iterator<String>` to iterate over them

   ```
   List<String> badWords = Arrays.asList(curse);
   Iterator<String> badWordIterator = badWords.iterator();
   while(badWordIterator.hasNext()) {
       if(badWordIterator.next().equalsIgnoreCase(event.getMessage())) {
           // logic
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this `if (event.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase(curse))`
you can use simple `for loop`

```
 for(int i=0;i<curse.length;i++){
    if (event.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase(curse[i])){
        event.setCancelled(true);
    player.sendMessage("Don't Swear");
    }
 }
```

or you can use `enhanced for loop` to check the values

```
for(String s:curse){
  if (event.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
    event.setCancelled(true);
    player.sendMessage("Don't Swear");
 }
}
```

Comment: You use `curse[i]` in one, but use an enhanced for in another.  Be consistent. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with a String[]. Iterate through it (preferably with an enhanced for loop) like this:

```
    for (String curse : curses) {
    }
```

and inside the loop put your check:

```
    for (String c : curse) {
        if (event.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase(c)) {
            event.setCancelled(true);
            player.sendMessage("Don't Swear");
        }
    }
```

So you iterate through the string array (therefore you get a result for each item in the array) and then check if the iterated item is equal to the message sent. By the way, I recommend asking these questions at spigotmc.org, as stackoverflow is not welcome to new people.